# How to find element<T> in Array[T] where <T> is an enum?

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

I'm only a couple of months in to TypeScript, delving into its inner workings. Perhaps someone can help improve my understanding.

In our angular2 application, we have an `enum` of privileges defined as:

```
export enum UserPrivileges{
  SUPER,
  USER,
  GUEST 
}
```

We include this type in a function definition as an array of the enum type:

```
checkPrivileges(userPrivileges: UserPrivileges[]) {...}
```

The pattern we have employed to find privileges for a user is:

```
this.isSuperUser = userPrivileges.includes(UserPrivileges[UserPrivileges.SUPER]);
```

**Problem**

TypeScript complains that *"Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to type 'UserPrivileges'"* because of the `Array.prorotype.includes()` method call (same problem with `.indexOf()`.)

Neither form of in-place casting I could think of worked:

```
this.isSuperUser = userPrivileges.includes(<string>UserPrivileges[UserPrivileges.SUPER]);
this.isSuperUser = userPrivileges.includes(UserPrivileges[UserPrivileges.<string>SUPER]);
```

We can 'cheat' the tsc linter and change the function signature to:

```
checkPrivileges(userPrivileges: string[]) {...}
```

...but then what's the point of using types?

This must be a common use-case, but I must be missing a necessary decorator? Is there a method I need to add to the enum type definition to allow it to be interpreted as a string?

**Edit**

To be clear, our backend returns the string tokens for privileges in an array, such that `userPrivileges = ["SUPER", "GUEST", "USER"]`. The `UserPrivileges` enum type was was intended to mimic this.

The old way, which worked (expect `true`):

```
userPrivileges.indexOf(UserPrivileges[UserPrivileges.SUPER]) > -1;
```

Because

- `UserPrivileges.SUPER` evaluates to `0` (because of the emitted JS Paarth explained)
- `UserPrivileges[0]` then evaluates to the string `"SUPER"`
- ...which is a value in `userPrivileges[]` from the backend.

Whereas these will both undesirably (but predictably) return `false`

```
userPrivileges.includes(UserPrivileges.SUPER);
userPrivileges.indexOf(UserPrivileges.SUPER) > -1;
```

for the same reasons as above: `userPrivileges[]` returned from the server does not include a value `0`.

*"When you feed an enum value back into itself, you're going to get back the string."* For the proposed solution to work, it *seems* that I would have to use the type's *numeric index* `UserPrivileges[0]` to get the string back to compare with the REST return?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `UserPrivileges[UserPrivileges.SUPER]` use `UserPrivileges.SUPER`

```
this.isSuperUser = userPrivileges.includes(UserPrivileges.SUPER);
```

Non-const enums in typescript are able to go backward and forward (they are objects with mappings for the string to the value and the value to the string). It might look something like this in the JS.

```
const UserPrivileges = {
    ['SUPER'] = 0,
    ['USER'] = 1,
    ['GUEST'] = 2,
    [0] = 'SUPER',
    [1] = 'USER',
    [2] = 'GUEST',
}
```

So when you feed an enum value back into itself, you're going to get back the string -- which explains the error you're seeing because `UserPrivileges.SUPER` resolves to `0`, and accessing a property based on a numerical index on an enum returns a string name.

---

Updated with information from the edit.

> To be clear, our backend returns the string tokens for privileges in an array, such that `userPrivileges = ["SUPER", "GUEST", "USER"]`

If this is true, then I suspect we may be speaking past each other. The variable `userPrivileges` isn't an `Array<T extends Enum>` This is an `Array<string>`.

At this point you have a couple of options. You can decide to work with strings and create UserPrivileges as

```
const UserPrivileges = {
    ['SUPER'] = 'SUPER',
    ['USER'] = 'USER',
    ['GUEST'] = 'GUEST',
}
```

or you could translate the list of strings to a true list of enums. Working from that list should then behave as expected.

Comment: This is an intriguing solution and exactly what I had observed. I'll accept from the number of upvotes that this is an idiomatic solution, so thank you. But it seems odd to me that I have to implement this double hash map myself. Is there a better alternative type definition I could use, or a different lookup pattern? It seems like a source of potential bugs: you have to remember to add both, with large lists it may not be obvious I don't know of automated tooling for detecting that kind of bug aside from a bad assignment inspection should I chance upon writing code that uses it.

Comment: I worry I may have been unclear @msanford. You do not have to implement that const, that is roughly what the typescript compiler generates for you when it emits the javascript. I was illustrating that you don't need to index into the enum type and explaining why you run into the error you run into. You should **definitely** continue defining enums the same way you did in your question. You should just be using them differently (first line of my answer)

Comment: Thank you for your elaborated explanation, Paarth. I've edited the question with some more information. The proposed solutions appears not to work because I would have to use `UserPrivileges.0`, not `UserPrivileges.SUPER`. I may still have misunderstood something, though.

Comment: @msanford added some updates in response to your edit.

Comment: Thanks! I'll share this with my team!